# iPhone - too sensitive rotation detection

Tags: iphone

I have a UIActionSheet based class. The ActionSheets created by this class are designed to vanish if a device orientation rotation is detected.

So, when this class begins I have

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and on the didRotate: i have the dismiss, that sends the ActionSheet away.

The only little, tiny problem is this: any vibration makes the actionSheet dismiss. Even tapping with a little bit more strength will make the popoup dismiss. Even if you are typing inside the actionSheet.

I don't have any accelerometer or coremotion enabled.

Any clues?

thanks

---

**EDIT**

I have discovered that the problem is that initially the orientation is being reported as UIDeviceOrientationUnknown and the trepidation makes it report the correct orientation. As UIDeviceOrientationUnknown is different from the correct orientation, this is seen as a rotation change...

Now I am doomed.

Comment: perhaps use the interfaceOrientation instead? it seems to be much less "jumpy" than the device orientation.

Comment: Thanks but I need the notification stuff. How do I do that still using the notification? I am not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to solve this cleanly, because the best methods for detecting the type of rotation you're interested in are called on `UIViewController` rather than `UIView`. In `UIViewController` you have `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, which tells you that an autorotation is about to occur. This method is on `UIViewController` because the controller has the responsibility of allowing or refusing autorotation. In order to convey this information to your view, you can post an `NSNotification` whenever a rotation is about to begin. Then, your `UIActionSheet` subclass can listen for this notification and shape itself appropriately. Alternatively, you could add a method to your subclass to notify it of rotations directly. It depends on how often you need to listen for autorotation in `UIView` subclasses and also how strong your need for reuse is.

Comment: Also, regarding the `UIDeviceOrientationUnknown`, that does make things harder. You may be able to come up with a heuristic that lets you figure out the initial orientation (e.g., aspect ratio < 1 means portrait) without it being reported.

Answer (score 2):

just check for which interfaceOrientation you're having. since iOS something, PortraitUp and facedown are supported interface orientations. What's happening to you is that portrait (when lying on a table) is switching to face-up and vice-versa. Just check for [that](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIDeviceOrientation). Please be careful, you're looking at UIDevice Orientation, which is NOT UIInterfaceOrientation!

Comment: This solved my similar problem where I am simulating the auto rotate feature manually using the notifications and the device orientations. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was doing

```
if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
//Do Stuff
} 
else
{
//Do Stuff
}
```

So I was going inside my else on FACEUP and FACEDown event which was wrong !

```
if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
//Do Stuff
} 
else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
{
//Do Stuff
}
```